# Output colours as table from console

Tags: javascript

Im using [Vibrant.js](http://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/) to extract colours from images in an effort to build a palette. I've got the script running and can see in console that the correct colours are being generated, but I'm not getting anything when I try to output them into a table … Here's my code.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'myImage.png')

img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var vibrant = new Vibrant(img);
    var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
    for (var swatch in swatches)
        if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch])
            console.log(swatch, swatches[swatch].getHex())

        var output = '<table><tr><td style=\"background-color:#"'+ swatch +'";\"></td></tr></table>';

    $('.palette').html(output);
});
```

Comment: table td content empty, put some value and try again

Comment: also you may need to use `swatches[swatch].getHex()` to output the hex in the background colour.

Comment: Thanks @Deckerz I've tried that but that strips the table out of `.palette` completely